# How to Identify Thunderbolt Compatible USB-C Extension

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I have an old Apple Thunderbolt Display that I’m using with an M1 MacBook Pro via Apple’s Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapter. The USB-C connector on the adapter is quite short and so I’d like to extend it. While I’d happily accept a recommendation for a specific USB-C extension cable someone's used in this way, my real question is how one might identify the correct cable. I’ve done some Googling around and ordered two extensions from Amazon that claim to be Thunderbolt 3 and 4 compatible, but neither works in practice. USB-C extension cables in general seem to be a bit of a speciality item (which I get) so none of my reputable dealers sell one which makes me wonder if I'm missing something. Is there a fundamental incompatibility here that makes this impossible?

Comment: I would avoid extending cables that carry data, like Thunderbolt, and just get a cable with the connector you need on each end. As you have found, extension cables can be, ummm... *flaky*

Comment: @SteveChambers I don't have that option here. AFAIK, the Apple adapter I'm already using is the only option I have for connecting a Thunderbolt Display to a Thunderbolt 3 port. If there are other options, I'd be interested in them.

Comment: I'd agree that your best bet is putting the laptop in an upright stand closer to the display, and then run a USB keyboard and mouse/trackpad from the Display.

Comment: Don’t get an extension cable and be sure it says “Thunderbolt” on it. Quality cables like Belkin and OWC are good bets.

Comment: I also have the Apple TB monitor, attached by the TB3-2 adapter to an M1 Mac Mini, but I use the TB port on the back of the monitor rather than the short built in cable that comes with the monitor.  You can attach a longer TB cable to the that port on the monitor, and connect the other end via the TB3-2 adapter to your Mac.

Comment: @arcdale I had no idea that was an option! Thanks for the suggestion, that might work!